# CiviCRM Webform membership Payments

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

I have multiple contacts in a webform (a family). Each contact can have a membership type with an associated fee. I want each contact to be have their membership renewed and the fee associated with their contact record and membership. What's happening at the moment is that the sum of membership fees is being charged to the primary contact (the one submitting the form). All individual memberships are being correctly renewed but without the associated membership fee attached to the membership record. I have soft credit set to none.

I have been unable to see where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think Webform is behaving correctly. The memberships are being renewed and a single payment is being recorded - that accurately reflects what happened when the form was submitted (it was one payment by one person, not several).

Comment: Is it possible to see what the breakdown of the payment is since we now lose the association of the payment with the contact/membership record?

Comment: It seems there are some issues when using a civicrm/webform to manage multiple contacts each with an associated membership type. It is true what Coleman says that the person submitting the form is the one who attracts the total payment.
There is no place where the breakdown of the individual membership fees can be displayed or reported (at least not as far as I can tell) when the webform is used in test mode (maybe it is different in live mode).
A search for contributions displays a single contribution with no breakdown. This makes it difficult to use in production. I hope I am wrong.

Comment: It'll work the same way in production. Try turning soft credits on.

Comment: I did and it still sums the fees and posts them to the primary contact. I'll do that again just to make sure that I did it correctly.

Comment: I turned on soft credits and tested again and I get the same result. The sum of the memberships are posted to the primary (submitting) contact. I must be missing something because even if I turn on soft credit the contribution created is not a soft credit with associated hard credits.

Comment: Hmm - when I try to view the contribution I get an error:

CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "Expected one PriceSet but found 25"

which must be the cause of the problem I am having. Does anyone know what might cause this?